# Cell height is something that ignored in webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit, html-table

I'm trying to play with tbody and and thead heights, and it turned out that webkit, contrary to other browsers, does not behave as I expected.

I've actually set `td` height.

[Here is](http://dabblet.com/gist/2489042) what I'm talking about

[image: how it rendered in webkit]

[image]

The question is - which browser behaves correctly and, even if webkit renders correctly, how can I make it render items just like in non-webkit browsers?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of the inner cells, then you could just insert a pseudo-element after the table: http://dabblet.com/gist/4332648

However, in that case there are better solutions like [paddings](http://dabblet.com/gist/4332671) etc :)

So, let's pretend we don't know the number of rows, but we know the height of a table. If we can somehow reserve the place for it, then we could make this table absolute positioned, insert very high pseudo-element and use `clip` to remove the unneeded space: http://dabblet.com/gist/4332690. And if we'd need a border, well, another pseudo-element would help — http://dabblet.com/gist/4332702.

I fear, that there could be only hacks to emulate what you want and no other ideal solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set both a height for `TABLE` and `TD`. Choose ONE.

Comment: well, what about cases when I just want to have some space no the bottom for some reasons - like this one ))))

Comment: In that case, wrap it in a DIV, and let the table collapse to the top. This gives you consistent look across browsers.

Comment: I've already done it and only after it posted this question))) The question is about how to fix it without any additional layout.

Answer (score 0):

for your cells, use min-height instead of height or both.

```
table {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
}
thead  td {
   min-height: 10px;
}

tbody {

}

tbody td {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is there something else in the code?  Because it works fine in all my browsers.  Perhaps some other styles or elements are interfering with the properties of those cells?!?!  Otherwise I would solve the problem by using padding or divs.